# Navbar drop-down menu problem when hovered upon

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, navbar

I created a `navbar` having a drop down menu displayed when the `button` is hovered upon.
This is the codepen: https://codepen.io/sahxil/pen/qBoVgXg

I have four problems with the navbar. If you look at the codepen and hover over `Solutions`:

1. You can see that the navbar gets displaced i.e. The other buttons shift towards the bottom.
2. A normal drop-down(triggered by `mouseover`) should collapse when
   the cursor no longer hovers over the nav button right? but it does
   not collapse. It collapses only the second time it is hovered
   upon.(See the codepen for more clarity).
3. The Nav Buttons when hovered upon get a red underline just below them having width of 30%, however, with buttons having a drop down, the underline is displaced(as you can see when you hover over `Solutions`.

Apart from this, another problem is that the `button` with drop-down menus are taking more width in the `navbar` even when they are not hovered on.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `#navbar {align-items: flex-start}` to tell flexbox to align your items correctly: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
2. Use `mouseout` as a companion to mouseover. Like mouseover, it also works on child elements.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event
3. Set `position: relative` on the parent element (`div.select-btn`). The reason this is happening is because your parent element is positioned as `static`. See this for an explanation of why that matters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#identifying_the_containing_block
4. I assume that by "button" you mean anchor elements? I don't see any actual button elements in your code. If you're finding that the spacing is too wide, then try adjusting `justify-content` on either `section#header` and/or on `ul#navbar`

Comment: thanks this worked. What code should I add in my javascript to solve [2] and by "button" I meant the navbar buttons which are anchor tags(sorry for that); also, by spacing I actually meant that, the anchor tag having a drop down menu is taking the same space as it's drop down menu, and I want it to be spaced out normally, the drop down menu should not affect it's spacing